# Xcode create action when switching views

Tags: xcode, sdk, view, action

hi there im having real trouble i have a main view which i am able to switch to 2 new views and i am able to switch back from both them views to the main view which is amazing

but i would like when i switch back from say the first new view to the main view i want a label to display text

and the same thing to happen when switching back from the second new view but with a different label

so to sum it up i want to switch views and have a label saying i switched back from view 1 being controlled by the button used to switch back

any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

Just put empty UILable on Main View. And set its value when you are doing transitions form first view to main view or 2nd view to main view.

Comment: how would i do that im currently switching like this


-(IBAction)backbutton:(id)sender{
    LevelSelect *second = [[LevelSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:NO];
}

Answer (score 0):

How are you switching between views?  If you are using a NavigationController, just set a variable on the main controller before you push/present the child controller.

Then, you can use that variable to set the label when you return to the parent view (viewWillAppear event).

Comment: im switching lik this  

-(IBAction)backbutton:(id)sender{
    LevelSelect *second = [[LevelSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:NO];
}

Comment: The same solution applies to this.   Add a line of code to your "backButton" method that sets a variable to indicate what you want the label to say upon return.   Then (to avoid having the label change prematurely) update it in either the "viewDidDisappear" or "viewWillAppear" methods of the original view controller based on the value of the variable you set in your backButton method.

Comment: is it possible to show me when my code as i really cannot get the hang of it its giving me a massive headache